# How do I delete an element from a list and then proceed to run it again without that element in a random choice selector?

Tags: python-3.x

What is wrong with this code? I want it so if "1" gets selected by random choice that it will re run the random choice code but without "1" in the list any longer.

```
import random
aList = ["1", "2", "3"]
bList = random.choice(aList)
print(bList)
if bList == "1":
    aList.pop(0)
    print(bList)
else:
    pass
if bList == "2":
    aList.pop(1)
    print(bList)
else:
    pass
if bList == "3":
    aList.pop(2)
    print(bList)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a while loop:

```
import random
aList = ["1", "2", "3"]
while aList:
    bList = random.choice(aList)
    print(bList)
    aList.pop(aList.index(bList))
```

Comment: Thanks you, but perhaps I worded it wrong. I want to be able to make an if bList = "a": statement while being able to delete "a" from the list and randomly choosing another to do the same with.

Comment: What's an "if bList = "a": statement"?

Answer (score 0):

When you check a random value, it has been removed from your list. Try to print `print(aList)` instead of `bList`. It will return values without random value.

```
if bList == "1":
    aList.pop(0)
    print(aList)
```

if you want to remove constantly random values,then you should use `while loop`.